# Why dynamic library can't load

Tags: c++, boost

I realized a mini shared library using boost c++ library. I compiled in my platform last boost version. I installed the library in the system. Then i tried to compile the project. All ok in compilation but when i try to load the library or checking the .so lib using ldd there are undefined variables.

This is the compilation output:

```
jni:
     [echo] Generating JNI headers
     [exec] mkdir -p target/c++
     [exec] g++ -c -Wall -fPIC -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include/ -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include/linux -I/usr/include/boost_1_66_0  -o target/c++/ext_concurrent_fiber_NativeFiber.o src/main/c++/ext_concurrent_fiber_NativeFiber.cpp
     [exec] mkdir -p target/c++
     [exec] g++ -c -Wall -fPIC -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include/ -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include/linux -I/usr/include/boost_1_66_0  -o target/c++/ext_concurrent_fiber_RecursiveMutex.o src/main/c++/ext_concurrent_fiber_RecursiveMutex.cpp
     [exec] mkdir -p target/c++
     [exec] g++ -c -Wall -fPIC -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include/ -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include/linux -I/usr/include/boost_1_66_0  -o target/c++/ext_concurrent_fiber_RWRecursiveMutex.o src/main/c++/ext_concurrent_fiber_RWRecursiveMutex.cpp
     [exec] g++ -Wall -g -O -fPIC -shared -L /usr/include/boost_1_66_0/stage/lib -lboost_fiber  -o  target/classes/libnativefibers.so target/c++/ext_concurrent_fiber_NativeFiber.o target/c++/ext_concurrent_fiber_RecursiveMutex.o target/c++/ext_concurrent_fiber_RWRecursiveMutex.o
```

This is makefile

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall -fPIC -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include/ -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include/linux -I/usr/include/boost_1_66_0
CPPFLAGS=-Wall -g -O -fPIC
LDFLAGS=-shared -L /usr/include/boost_1_66_0/stage/lib -lboost_fiber
SOURCES_DIR=src/main/c++
OBJECTS_DIR=target/c++
EXECUTABLE=target/classes/libnativefibers.so

SOURCES=$(shell find '$(SOURCES_DIR)' -type f -name '*.cpp')
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:$(SOURCES_DIR)/%.cpp=$(OBJECTS_DIR)/%.o)

all: $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)


    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)  -o  $(EXECUTABLE) $^



$(OBJECTS):
     mkdir -p $(OBJECTS_DIR)

    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)  -o $@ $(SOURCES_DIR)/$(basename $(notdir $@)).cpp

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJECTS_DIR) $(EXECUTABLE)
```

This is output from ld target/classes/libnativefibers.so

```
ld: attenzione: impossibile trovare il simbolo d'ingresso _start; l'indirizzo iniziale non viene impostato
target/classes/libnativefibers.so: riferimento non definito a "boost::fibers::scheduler::set_algo(boost::intrusive_ptr<boost::fibers::algo::algorithm>)"
target/classes/libnativefibers.so: riferimento non definito a "vtable for boost::fibers::context"
target/classes/libnativefibers.so: riferimento non definito a "boost::fibers::fiber::detach()"
target/classes/libnativefibers.so: riferimento non definito a "typeinfo for boost::fibers::context"
target/classes/libnativefibers.so: riferimento non definito a "boost::fibers::recursive_mutex::lock()"
target/classes/libnativefibers.so: riferimento non definito a "ontop_fcontext"
target/classes/libnativefibers.so: riferimento non definito a "jump_fcontext"
target/classes/libnativefibers.so: riferimento non definito a "boost::fibers::context::~context()"
target/classes/libnativefibers.so: riferimento non definito a "boost::fibers::fiber::start_()"
target/classes/libnativefibers.so: riferimento non definito a "boost::fibers::recursive_mutex::unlock()"
target/classes/libnativefibers.so: riferimento non definito a "make_fcontext"
target/classes/libnativefibers.so: riferimento non definito a "vtable for boost::fibers::algo::shared_work"
target/classes/libnativefibers.so: riferimento non definito a "boost::fibers::fiber::join()"
target/classes/libnativefibers.so: riferimento non definito a "boost::fibers::context::active()"
target/classes/libnativefibers.so: riferimento non definito a "boost::fibers::context::terminate()"
target/classes/libnativefibers.so: riferimento non definito a "boost::fibers::context::get_id() const"
target/classes/libnativefibers.so: riferimento non definito a "boost::context::stack_traits::default_size()"
target/classes/libnativefibers.so: riferimento non definito a "boost::fibers::recursive_mutex::try_lock()"
```

Using  a Test class there result is :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/libnativefibers4038906104222457167.so: /tmp/libnativefibers4038906104222457167.so: undefined symbol: _ZTIN5boost6fibers7contextE
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1824)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
    at ext.concurrent.fiber.NativeFiber.loadLibrary(NativeFiber.java:42)
    at ext.concurrent.fiber.NativeFiber.<clinit>(NativeFiber.java:11)
    at ext.concurrent.Test.main(Test.java:8)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cannot compile boost::fiber offical examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46515178/cannot-compile-boostfiber-offical-examples)

Comment: following the other post i resolved one problem . Now there is last error:
warning: impossible to find the entry symbol _start; the start address is not set

Comment: Your Makefile is weird mix of everything. You have `CPPFLAGS` and `CFLAGS`, you are passing first when linking, second one when compiling. You are mixing compiling and linking options. `-shared` should be passed when linkng, `-fPIC` when compiling code. Just remove `CPPFLAGS` from your makefile.

Comment: Sorry maybe i dont understanc correctly : above already there is "g++ -Wall -g -O -fPIC -shared"

Comment: I tried to remove from makefile the label CPPFLAGS and his content but same result

Comment: Using `-shared` should fix the issues for you. It looks like you already pass it, so everything should work. You should make sure it is their when everything is being linked.

Comment: even if that error continue to be present , from java i can load the library. I dont know if it is important or maybe is a missing symbol  inside jni.

Comment: The `fiber` boost library requires C++11, as described [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/fiber/doc/html/fiber/overview.html). I suggest that you try to add the flag `-std=c++11` to `CPPFLAGS`.

Comment: I tried but there is same error